# Aframe Videosphere how to detect end of video

Tags: aframe

Am attempting to play another video directly when the first videos finishes playing.

Is there a way to detect the end of the first video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video node emits events like `ended`, or `paused`.
You can check them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

---

That being said, you can create a component, which will listen for the event:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
 init: function() {
   var vid = document.querySelector("#myVideo")
   vid.addEventListener("ended", (e) => {
     //change the sphere material + play the new video
   }
})
```